# Synchronize Table Re-sizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the JQuery plugin [colResizable](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/#samples) ([@alvaro-prieto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615805/3639370)) to create re-sizable tables in my application and have two individual table objects (same column count). However, I am looking for a way to resize the two tables at the same time (e.g. Updating Table 1's columns also updates Table 2's columns synchronously). See the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/) for an interactive implementation of the plugin.

```
$("#sample").colResizable({liveDrag:true});

$("#sample2").colResizable({
    liveDrag:true,
    gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
    draggingClass:"dragging" });
```

I've noticed you can specify a callback function such as `onDrag` that consistently fires when 'dragging' a column. While this helps me get closer to a solution, I am still unaware of a concrete method to synchronize the tables' updates.

I am looking to avoid modifying the source if possible and find a suitable JS/JQ solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelly the plugin doesn't seem to have a way to resize the column programatically. Now, you can use the `onDrag` event to simulate a resize in the other table's columns.

So far I've been able to do so, but this "hacky" way doesn't seem to work that well.

Here is the function that I call every time a column is dragged:

```
function syncTableWidth(e){
    var parent = e.currentTarget;

    $("table").filter(function(){return $(this).attr("id") != $(parent).attr("id")}).each(function(){
        //Match the width
        $("tr th", this).each(function(index){
            $(this).css("width",$("tr th:nth-of-type("+(index+1)+")", parent).css("width"))
        });
        //Match the grip's position
        $(this).prev().find(".JCLRgrip").each(function(index){
            $(this).css("left",$(parent).prev().find(".JCLRgrip:nth-of-type("+(index+1)+")").css("left"));
       });
    }); 
}
```

Now you can call this function like this:

```
$("#my_table").colResizable({
    liveDrag:true,
    gripInnerHtml:"<div class='grip'></div>", 
    draggingClass:"dragging",
    onDrag: syncTableWidth
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euka4rm3/407/) I was working on. Hopefully it wil lhelp you or someone else keep improving it.

Comment: Ah, yes the functionality is exactly what I am looking for! It is indeed "hacky" but the need for this to be modular is not necessary, so possibly with a little tweaking this will be perfect for my use cases.

Comment: So far it has a problem. Try alternating dragging on one table an then in another, you will see what I mean. It kinds of "jump" to the previous position. It works well if you use only one table to control the other ones.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. In my revision, I will have explicitly defined elements. Maybe the disambiguation will correct this.