# Support resizing two side by side iframes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a web page where I need to show two iFrames side by side, and allow a user to resize them horizontally (so they can easily see the complete contents of either side).

My code looks like this:

```
<div style="padding:30px">
  <table style="width:100%;border:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <td class="cLeft cSide">
        <iframe class="cFrame" src="{MyLeftPage}">
        </iframe>
      </td>
      <td class="cRight cSide">
        <iframe class="cFrame" src="{MyRightPage}">
        </iframe>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dchayn8t/23/)

The problem with using the standard approaches as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6157119/1555435) (Thanks user!) is that when you have iFrames and you move the mouse over them, the `$(document).mousemove()` stops firing.

The trick is to have a column in the middle, and have a div that shows up when you click the column. Since the div is in the parent page, the `mousemove` event keeps firing, allowing you to easily resize it.

Here's what the final HTML looks like:

```
<div style="user-select:none;padding:30px">
  <table style="width:100%;border:0px;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <td class="cLeft cSide">
        <iframe class="cFrame" src="{MyLeftPage}">
        </iframe>
      </td>
      <td class="resize-bar">
        <div class="resize-panel"></div>
      </td>
      <td class="cRight cSide">
        <iframe class="cFrame" src="{MyRightPage}">
        </iframe>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.resize-bar {
  width: 5px;
  cursor: col-resize;
  position:relative;
  background-color: #AAA;
  margin:20px;
}
.resize-panel {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #DDDDDD00;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:-2px;
  right:-2px;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
.resize-panel.rx {
    left:-400px;
    right:-400px;
}

.cSide {
    min-width:200px;
}

.cFrame {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  height: calc(100vh - 170px);
  overflow-x:scroll;
}
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  var pressed = false;

  $("table td").mousedown(function(e) {
    pressed = true;
    $(".resize-panel").addClass("rx");
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(".resize-panel").mousedown(function(e) {
    pressed = false;
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1 && pressed) {
      var ww = $(window).width();
      var cPos = e.pageX;

      if (cPos < 0.20 * ww) cPos = 0.2 * ww;
      if (cPos > 0.80 * ww) cPos = 0.8 * ww; {
        $(".cLeft").width(cPos);
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    if (pressed) {
      $(".resize-panel").removeClass("rx");
      pressed = false;
    }
  });
});
```